# display the latest date the number appeared

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data in the format below.

```
A       B C D E F  G
aug1    5 4 2 7 55 43
aug4    6 7 8 44 33 22
aug5    5 4 2 7 55 43
aug6    5 4 2 7 55 43
aug8    5 4 2 7 55 43

column Z
3
4
5
6
```

I want to be able to display the latest date from Column A, where ANY of the columns (B.C.D.E.F.G) had the number found in column Z. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data shown I'm going to assume that column A is in ascending order so what I am doing is finding the last row that contains the value wanted.  This formula is entered using **ctrl+shift+enter**

```
=INDIRECT("A"&MAX(ROW($B$2:$G$6)*--($B$2:$G$6=Z2)))
```

The indirect takes a text entry such as A1 and converts it to a cell reference so indirect("A1") would return the value in A1.  Using this with column A and the max row will find the date.

The max formula takes the rows from all values you are looking at and multiplies it by a boolean (1 if true, 0 if false) if the cell matches the value in cell Z2.  Note that if cell Z2=3 then it only matches 3 not 43 or 33.

This gives an array with all rows that match the value in Z2 and returns the max value into the indirect function.

Results for your examples

```
3 = ref error (no 3 in data)
4 = Aug 8
5 = Aug 8
6 = Aug 4
```